# Unterscheidung von "r" und "n" in Richtungsangabe

Tags: difference, etymology

In meinem Dialekt wird nicht das typische Bairische "óve" und "affe" für "runter" und "rauf" verwendet. Stattdessen verwenden wir "rundda" und "rauf", aber auch "nundda" und "nauf".

Was komisch ist, ist dass die Richtungsangaben sehr einheitlich sind:
rundda - nundda; rauf - nauf; riva - niva; rei - nei; raus - naus

Die, die mit einem "r" anfangen, bezeichnen eine Bewegung zu einem, während die, die mit einem "n" beginnen, eine Bewegung von einem weg bezeichnen.

Meine Frage ist, woher kommt diese Entwicklung? Machen andere Sprachen so einen Unterschied?

Comment: Im Standardschriftdeutsch entspricht dem *hin-* und *her-*, aber vielleicht gibt es ja trotzdem Interessantes dazu zu sagen.

Comment: Im Grimm steht dazu unter "hin": *geht in der form zurück, wenn es das unbetonte glied gewisser verbindungen bildet, und verflüchtigt sich oft bis auf seinen auslaut, so dasz für hinab, hinan, hinauf, hinaus, hinein, hinunter, hinüber in vertraulicher und volksmäsziger rede auch gilt nab, nan, nauf, nein, nunter, nüber;*

Comment: Ausserdem gibt's noch "auf[e|i]" und "ab[e|i]" als Richtungsangaben, die "herauf", "hinauf" und "herab", "hinab" anders verkürzt haben.

Comment: Ich bin neugierig. Was ist denn dein Dialekt?

Comment: @Iris Ich lebe nahe Ingolstadt. Unser Dialekt hat einige Schwäbische einschläge und ich denke das das auch einer ist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

»Rauf« ist von »herauf« abgeleitet und »nauf« von »hinauf«. Dasselbe gilt sinngemäß für »runter« und »nunter«, »rei« (herein) und »nei« (hinein) usw.

### her

Die Vorsilbe »her« (bzw. das »r« im Dialekt) bedeutet eine Bewegung, deren Ziel die Position des Sprecher ist.

- »Komm her«, »kum her«: Die angesprochene Person wird aufgefordert, sich auf den Sprecher zuzubewegen.
- »Komm herauf«, »kum rauf«: Wie zuvor, mit der Zusatzinformation, dass sich der Sprecher auf einer höheren Position als die angesprochene Person befindet.
- »Komm heraus«, »kum raus«: Wie zuvor, der Sprecher befindet sich außen, die angesprochene Person innen.

Es ist auch möglich, die Position des Sprecher, die das Ziel der Bewegung ist, näher zu spezifizieren:

- »Komm zum Auto her«, »kum zum Auto her«: Der Sprecher befindet sich in einem Auto oder in unmittelbarer Nähe eines Autos und fordert jemanden auf, sich auf die Position von Sprecher und Auto zuzubewegen.
- »Komm aus deinem Loch heraus«, »kum aus deim Loch raus«: Die angesprochene Person befindet sich in einem Loch, der Sprecher ist außerhalb des Lochs. Die angesprochene Person wird aufgefordert, das Loch zu verlassen.

### hin

Die Vorsilbe »hin« (bzw. das »n« im Dialekt) bedeutet eine Bewegung, deren Ziel eine andere Position als die des Sprecher ist.

- »Gehe zum Auto hin«, »geh zum Auto hin«: Die angesprochene Person wird aufgefordert, sich auf etwas anderes/jemand anderen zuzubewegen.
- »Gehe den Berg hinauf«, »geh den Berg nauf«: Wie zuvor, mit der Zusatzinformation, dass sich das Ziel auf einer höheren Position als die angesprochene Person befindet.
- »Gehe in den Garten hinaus«, »geh in d'n Gortn naus«: Wie zuvor, das Ziel befindet sich außen, die angesprochene Person innen.

Ohne explizite Angabe eines Zieles kann »*hin...*« auch »vom Sprecher weg« bedeuten:

- »Gehe hinauf«, »geh nauf«: Sprecher und angesprochene Person befinden sich beide unten und die angesprochene Person wird aufgefordert, nach oben (also vom Sprecher weg) zu gehen.
- »Gehe hinaus«, »geh naus«: Beide befinden sich innen, die angesprochene Person soll nach außen (also vom Sprecher weg) gehen.

Das funktioniert im modernen Deutsch aber nicht mit »hin« alleine«, sondern nur wenn es als Vorsilbe verwendet wird. Nur in der alten Phrase »Gehet hin in Frieden«, mit der ein christlicher Priester die Kirchgänger am Ende der Messe verabschiedet, wird »hin« (als allein stehendes Wort) noch in einer Aufforderung, sich von Sprecher wegzubewegen, verwendet.

---

### Situation in anderen Sprachen

Die Unterscheidung zwischen hin und her wird auch in vielen anderen Sprachen getroffen. Einige haben dafür sogar eigene grammatische Fälle. Während Deutsch nur die vier Fälle *Nominativ, Genitiv, Dativ* und *Akkusativ* hat, gibt es andere Sprachen, die andere Fälle haben, und mitunter auch deutlich mehr Fälle. Vor allem die finno-ugrischen Sprachen, zu denen neben Finnisch und Ungarisch auch Estnisch gehört, haben fast für alles, was man in anderen Sprachen mit Adpositionen ausdrückt, eigene Fälle. (Finnisch hat 15 Fälle und Ungarisch hat sogar 31.)

### Ablativ

In den finno-ugrischen Sprachen ist der Ablativ aber jener Fall, der eine Bewegung weg von einem Objekt beschreibt

Finnisch:

> das Haus = talo
>   vom Haus weg = talolta

Im Gegensatz zum Deutschen wird der Aspekt der Wegbewegung nicht in einer Modifikation der Präposition (aus -> hinaus, unten -> hinunter) sondern in Beugung der Bezeichnung des Ausgangspunktes der Bewegung beschrieben.

### Allativ

Das ist der grammatische Fall, der eine Bewegung auf ein Ziel zu beschreibt:

Finnisch:

> das Haus = talo
>   zum Haus hin = talolle

Comment: Letzter Absatz: "Der Computer ist hin" ist durchaus noch eine alleinstehende "weg von mir"-Verwendung von *hin* in der modernen Umgangssprache.

Comment: @tofro: Ja, aber über einen sehr weiten Umweg. Das Wort »hin« hat heute vier verschiedene Bedeutungen, die sich in insgesamt neun Detail-Bedeutungen aufspalten lassen. Siehe https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/hin Wovon in meiner Antwort die Rede war, war die Bedeutung [1a] im verlinkten Wiktionary-Artikel. Du sprichst aber [3b] (kaputt) an. Diese Bedeutung ist von [3d] (tot) abgeleitet, was wiederum auf »hinüber gegangen« im Sinn von »ins Jenseits gegangen« zurückgeht, und erst hier findet man die Wegbewegung (vom Diesseits weg). Daran denkt aber niemand mehr, der ein Gerät als »hin« bezeichnet.